# after mouseover back to previous state with mouseout? -without setting fixed values

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, mouseover, mouseout

I am working on a color-picker to change CSS-Properties of SVG-Images with JS.
My rudimentary code works so far to change the fill-color of the SVG-Path  on click and on mouseover.

I want the fill-color fall back to the previous 'selected' color after leaving the button with the mouse.
I know I could define a fixed value for the mouseout-function. But if a user selects a color via click I **want the clicked choice to be set** (to later put them into a php-variable) **and the quick mouseover**-'blend-ins' really should **just be shown temporarily for the moment** the user hovers..

So to say: exit the mouseover-state through falling back to the click-state if user clicked before.

Momentarily the color will be set to the mouseover choice; this should only be a visual guidance for the user, not the setting itself.

Probably my JS-Example can explain better than my words:

```js
$(function(){
$("#s01aFI").css("fill","#fff");

  $("#fw01-f01").mouseover(function(){
  $("#s01aFI").css("fill","#e53741");
  });
  $("#fw01-f01").click(function(){
  $("#s01aFI").css("fill","#e53741");
  });
  $("#fw01-f01").mouseout(function(){
  $("#s01aFI").css("fill","RECENT-STATE");
  });

  ...

});
```

```css
.f01 { background-color:#e53741; }
.f02 { background-color:#419327; }
...
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
*JS-Function*
</script>

<svg>
<path id="s01aFI" d="***"/>
</svg>

<button id="fw01-f01" class="farbwahler f01">01</button>
<button id="fw01-f02" class="farbwahler f02">02</button>
...
```

P.S. If you can give me a hint for redundancy also it would be heavenly; since I am about to do this for lots of colors and elements and I am new to JS since yesterday. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you right you wants this code:

$(this) - works with current button with hover

```js
$(function(){
  var preview = $("#s01aFI");
  var colorBut = $(".farbwahler"); //any button
  var curColor = "gold";

  colorBut.mouseover(function(){
    $(this).data('clicked', false);
    var color = $(this).css('background-color');
    preview.css("fill",color);
  });
 
  colorBut.mouseout(function(){
    var isClick = $(this).data('clicked');
    if(!isClick){
      var color = $(this).css('background-color');
      preview.css("fill",curColor );
    }
  });
  
  colorBut.click(function(){
    var color = $(this).css('background-color');
    preview.css("fill",color);
    curColor = color;
    $(this).data('clicked', true);
  });
});
```

```css
.f01 { background-color:#e53741; }
.f02 { background-color:#419327; }

svg {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<svg>
  <path id="s01aFI" d="M 10,110 L 10,10 L 40,50 L 70,10 L 100,50 L 130,10 L 130,110 z"
          fill="gold" stroke="orange" stroke-width="5"/>
</svg>

<button id="fw01-f01" class="farbwahler f01">01</button>
<button id="fw01-f02" class="farbwahler f02">02</button>
```

Comment: Yes. Thank you! You are worth of the crown for this answer. :)
Not just that it´s working, it´s also a perfect exercise for me to follow your lines and see the difference between my idea and how it actually works.